# In Visual Studio (2013), is it possible to get intellisense to look up and import a class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Is there any way to get intellisense to look up and insert a class into the code?  Currently, it only does this when the namespace of the class is already included in the `using` statements at the top of the file.  However, it won't search other namespaces referenced in the project to find a matching class.

In Eclipse, for example, I can type part of a class name in the code, and then auto-complete will display a drop down with the list of possible matching classes to select which one to insert into the code.  (And then Eclipse adds the `import` statement for that class at the top.)

So far, the closest thing I have found is, if I type out the full class name in the code, VS will show a little icon button which will then add the `using` statement for that class.  However, that's not so helpful if you don't remember and type the exact class name (case-sensitive) (and it doesn't save nearly as many key-strokes).

**UPDATE**
TankorSmash suggested Resharper. [This page on Resharper 8](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/comparisonMatrix_R8_vs2013.html) for Visual Studio indicates that Visual Studio does not offer

> Code completion is context-driven, can suggest types and extension methods from the entire solution, import namespaces, generate code

So based on this, I would say the solution has to be to purchase Resharper.

Comment: I don't about standard VS but if you get the paid Resharper it lets you do stuff like this for sure.

Comment: hovering over the name of the class dosen't give you suggestions like `using ...` ? if not is odd because I don't have Resharper and always get suggestions

Comment: @IoanaStoian: not sure I understand your comment.  How do you hover over the name of a class if you haven't typed it yet?  In Eclipse, I type the first few letters of a class, press auto-complete (ctrl-space), and then Eclipse pops up a list of suggested classes where you can select which one to import and insert into the code.  This is *very* helpful when you don't remember the exact class name.  In VS, you have to know the *exact* class name, and type it correctly, then you can press [ctrl]-. and it gives a list of classes to import.

Comment: You don't have to type the exact name, you could type a few letters and then press ctr+. or hover over your few letters. (https://postimg.org/image/vmiot97mj/)

Comment: @IoanaStoian:  I looked at the image you posted.  You have already typed a complete statement.  Not sure if you have ever used Eclipse, but you don't need to type a complete statement to get the intellisense help.  For example, if somewhere in my solution exists a class called "ObjectMapper", and I need to type code:  `ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper()`, I want to just type the beginning few letters:  `Obj` and hit autocomplete to see the suggestions.  (This is what we do in Eclipse.)   Your example shows you have already typed the entire line of code.

Comment: I've typed Empl which is from Employee, and Employee would appear to me as a suggestion. Also Employee class and the class I try to create an Employee are not in the same namespace

Comment: @IoanaStoian: I keep trying that, but nothing happens (unless it is either same namespace or already in the `using` statements).

Comment: I especially created a case with no previous `using` or same namespace. I have Community edition so I guess it should be the same for whatever version you use...

Comment: @TankorSmash: Resharper is the bomb!  Thanks for recommendation. My coding experience is completely different now!

Comment: Yeah man, it almost makes coding too easy. Glad you liked it.